# Clustering Standard Errors for Panel Data with multiple clusters

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics, regression, statistics, paneldata

I have a Group-Firm-Year panel data set (i.e., multiple firms make up a group). Suppose I have exogenous variation at the group level over time. In a panel regression with firm and time fixed effects that estimates the effect of this exogenous group variation on some firm outcome variable, should my standard errors be clustered at the firm or group level? Should I two-way cluster as well (within-time)?

Assume that the variation at the Group-year level is truly random.